# What can I do to start a terminal in a X server at boot without giving away root priveleges?

Tags: permissions, xorg, root

The problem:

I run Linux on an arcade machine with a monitor that accepts a 15kHz signal. I can't see anything until the X server starts and a [modeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFree86_Modeline) gets the GPU to output the correct signal.

My solution:

Start something like xterm so I can have a terminal on the machine's display.

This approach has problems, the main one is that if I start the X server as root, then xterm is logged in as the root user.

I don't want to have a fully fledged window manager, I just use `xinit` to start the server.

Is there a good solution to this? Should I use `su` to start xterm as a different user?

Comment: Perhaps use a serial console instead?  I don't see how starting an `xterm` would help you anyway, since `xterm` won't start before the X server starts either.  Or perhaps I didn't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What do you mean? I can get the X server to start xterm using xinitrc

Comment: You still won't see anything until the X server starts.

Comment: I know, that's not what I'm trying to solve. I just want the ability to see the terminal on the screen. I don't care if I have to wait for the X server to start.

Comment: Then don't run `xinit` as root.  There is absolutely no reason for the X server to run as root, use `sudo` to start it as some unprivileged user.

Comment: 1. Don't run X as root (the only reason to do so in if you want a ton of programs to break and your computer to be insecure. 2) Don't use ``xinit``. ``startx`` has been around for a long time and is dramatically more sane.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Is it possible to start xterm in such a way that it displays the login prompt you see when the system boots up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always run an X session as a particular user, restarting it when it exits, then you could do worse than to install `nodm`.  It is very small and will take care of all that.  It doesn't require any window manager; all it needs is a `.xsession` file in the target user's home directory.

If you really want to go with `startx`, you could make your `xterm` execute `login` as its command with `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have a login prompt in graphics mode. This is called a [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)). Instead of calling `xinit`, install a display manager and make sure your system runs it when it starts (that's the case in most distribution if you install a package containing a display manager). You can install the old-school, minimalist [xdm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDM_(display_manager)), or a less barebones but still small one such as [SLiM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLiM) or [LightDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM), or some fancier ones.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I actually need an application to run _without_ logging in to begin with. The idea is that if it crashes someone will still be able to log in and poke about. What I might do is run that application with xinit or startx, then if it crashes, launch xdm, which can then start xterm in .xsession. Does that seem like a decent solution?

Comment: @CameronBall You didn't mention an application in your question. Do you mean that you want to start an X application when the machine starts, and you also want an opportunity to log in? If so, I suggest that you run an X server with only the application running full screen (kiosk mode) on one [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), and xdm on another virtual console.

Comment: That's correct. I'm not too keen on the idea of having them on different virtual consoles. The whole idea is that if the application crashes, a message or something can be displayed and they can log in. The person using this may not be linux savvy and not understand about virtual consoles - which is why I'd prefer to keep it all on one console. Perhaps I could simply add the application to /etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup and have my xterm in .xsession

Comment: @CameronBall Then start xdm when the application crashes. I'm sorry but it's difficult to provide a helpful answer when the scenario keeps changing with every comment you post.

Comment: Starting xdm when it crashes/is closed seems like the best solution.